# Printing intermediate value in recursive function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am new to Haskel and want to learn it. I want to print intermediate value in recursive function in haskell but i am stuck in parse error on input "=" on line b= b+50.

```
`main' t s a b c  
    | t > s    = 0  
    | otherwise = do 
        print a
        print b
        print c
        b = b + 50
        c = b + 2 * a
        main' (t+1) s (a+1) b c `
```

the C equivalent for this code is

```
 int calculate(t,s,a,b,c)
 {
     printf( "%d,%d,%d",a,b,c);
     if(t > s)
        return 0;
     else
      {
           b = b + 50;
           c = b + 2 * a;
           return calculate (t+1,s,a,b,c);
       }

    }
    int main()
    {
         calculate(0,10,2,6,7);
         return 0;  
    }`
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. It is not so difficult to do in C but I could not figure out how to do it in Haskel.

Comment: please post an error you get from compiler

Comment: In do blocks you need `let` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As PyRulez says in his comment, you need to use `let` syntax in do blocks. However, you are also going to run into issues because your function parameters, like all values in Haskell, are immutable. You will need to do something like:

```
let b' = b + 5
let c' = b' + 2 * a
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to print some intermediate value, you don't need to have your function in the IO world:
you can use the Debug.Trace module:

```
import Debug.Trace

func :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
func 0 _ _ _ = 0
func t a b c = trace ("a="++(show a)++" b="++(show b)++" c="++(show c)) $ recurs
    where recurs = func (t-1) (a+1) (b+50) (b+2*a)
```

it gives me:

```
> func 5 1 1 1
a=1 b=1 c=1
a=2 b=51 c=3
a=3 b=101 c=55
a=4 b=151 c=107
a=5 b=201 c=159
```